# Wordpress Admin Email Constantly receiving password changed

Tags: wordpress

Would like to seek help as to why am I constantly receiving password changed notification from different users despite security and bot trap plugin are installed.

Anyone has any idea as in why this is happening or is it normal?

[image: Email notification of password change]

Comment: You should ask your question on https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ where more people may know the answer.

Comment: Alright O.Jones, will post this over there. thank you